# Drupal internalURL rewrite

Tags: url, drupal, routes, drupal-9

I am trying to do something very simple, but can't seem to find a way to do it. What I want is to have a URL in the form of `/en/products/accessories+software` internally route to `/en/products?accessories+software`.

`/en/products` is an existing page, whatever comes after are basically filters, which are appended to the URL so they can be linked directly. Now it works by appending it as query parameters, but using `/filtersHere` would be preferred. But this of course results in a 404 error.

Site is running D9.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Drupal's Routing system and make dynamic arguments on URL?

In the module.routing.yml, something like below should do:

```yaml
module.mypath:
  # Dynamic arguments enclosed in { }.
  path: '/book/export/{type}/{node}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\module\Controller\MyController::index'
```

More details available in the official doc:
[Drupal - Structure of routes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/structure-of-routes)